# Rescale matrix of zeros with point

Tags: python

I have a matrix

```
import numpy as np
matrix =np.zeros((5,5))
matrix[(3,3)] = 1
```

and I would like to scale it to size for example `50x50` because then I need to save it to image

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.fromarray(matrix,'RGB').save('my.png')
```

How can I scale it?

Comment: refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50159625/how-to-scale-each-column-of-a-matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*How can I scale it?*

If desired size divide evenly by actual size you might harness [Kronecker product](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.kron.html). For example sake let say you want to upscale your 5x5 to 15x15 size, we find that 15/5 gives `3` so we will use `np.ones((3,3))`:

```
import numpy as np
matrix =np.zeros((5,5))
matrix[(3,3)] = 1
result = np.kron(matrix, np.ones((3,3)))
print(matrix)
print(result)
```

output for matrix

```
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

output for result

```
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

If you wish to use more advanced scaling algorithm I suggest using OpenCV's [cv2.resize](https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d6e/tutorial_py_geometric_transformations.html) function which does deal with images as `numpy.array`s.